# Long-Time Average Expected Number of Supportes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains, binomial-distribution

3 football clubs run an ad campaign

A supporter of club A has 10% chance switching B and 1% switching C

A supporter of club B has a 5% chance of switching to C and 1% of switching to A

A supported of club C has a 6% chance of switching to A and 2% of switching to B

10000 potential supporters

Find Long Run average expected supporters for each club

0.89 O.O1 0.06 = 0.96 = 3200

0.1  0.94 0.02 = 1.06 = 3533

0.01 0.05 0.92 = 0.98 = 3267

I don't think this is correct, 3x3 matrix, tried formatting but won't work am I on the right track with a 3x3 matrix?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Yeah will update now

Answer (score 1):

We can construct a system of linear equations to figure out the number each of the teams has after a long time:

$$A = 0.89A+0.01B+0.06C\\
B = 0.1A + 0.94B + 0.02C\\
C = 0.01A + 0.05B + 0.92C$$

This is how the numbers of supporters change in one "iteration". If we subtract the left side from both sides, we end up with a nice system in terms of $A, B,$ and $C$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}-0.11 & 0.01 & 0.06\\
0.1 &-0.06 & 0.02\\
0.01 & 0.05 & -0.08\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\\C\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Solving this yields $B$ and $C$: $B = \frac{41A}{19}$ and $C = \frac{28A}{19}$, however leaves $A$ free to be any number.

To figure out exactly how many fans each team ends up with, we must set $A+B+C$ equal to $10000$. This will be easily solved for $A$, given that $B$ and $C$ are defined as fractions of it.

$$A+B+C = \frac{19A+41A+28A}{19} = \frac{88}{19}A=10000\\
\implies A = \frac{190000}{88}\approx2159.$$

Thus, after a long time, club $A$ will have about $2159$ fans, $B$ will have $4659$ fans, and club $C$ will have $3182$ fans.

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I had the original matrix but didnt know to subtract A, B and C in order to get minus. I also don't understand how this fully works in relation to 10000. Do I simply use -0.11, 0.1 and 0.01 as a distribution state until a certain point?

Comment: I will add this to my answer, hold on.

Comment: Thanks whenever you can I appreciate it

Comment: Hi Austin thanks again. I don't fully understand how you found 41A/19 =B and likewise for C however. Even if you could point me towards a tutorial video that may help thanks again

Comment: I got those values by solving the matrix equation. This is in every way equivalent to simply solving the original system of equations. If you are interested in understanding and using linear algebra to solve equations, this resource will help you start your way down the rabbit hole: (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) Otherwise, simply applying algebra to the original three equations will give you the same answer.

Comment: Also, surprisingly enough, the wikipedia page on the subject is very good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations